# Loading Image in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want an image to be displayed in the center of the layout. I could not figure it out. Is there any way to display the image on the center of the layout and be there till the animation is stopped?

Here is my code.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

Builder.load_string('''                               
<Loading>:
    canvas:
        Rotate:
            angle: root.angle
            origin: self.center
        Color:
            rgb: .0, 0, -.1
        Ellipse:    
            size: min(self.size), min(self.size)
            pos: 0.5*self.size[0] - 0.5*min(self.size), 0.5*self.size[1] - 0.5*min(self.size)
        Color:
            rgb: .5, 0, 1
        Ellipse:    
            size: 30, 30
            pos: 0.5*root.size[0]+25, 0.8*root.size[1]-25
''')


class Loading(FloatLayout):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Loading, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        anim = Animation(angle = 1009, duration=2.5)
        anim += Animation(angle = 1900, duration=2.5)
        anim.repeat = True
        anim.start(self)

    def on_angle(self, item, angle):
       if angle == 360:
           item.angle = 0


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):

        return Loading()

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Definitely check the [examples](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/examples) folder in Kivy repository.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your canvas should be "loose" like that. Place it inside of a Widget, this will let you use Kivy's various layouts to arrange things. It will also let you insert an Image above the widget and without making the image spin around.

A second thing, use rgba so you can specify transparencies for the background. This example below works for me, just replace the Builder string with this:

```
"""<Loading>:
FloatLayout:
    Image:
        source: 'logo.png'
    Widget:
        canvas:
            Rotate:
                angle: root.angle
                origin: self.center
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 0

            Ellipse:    
                size: min(self.size), min(self.size)
                pos: 0.5*self.size[0] - 0.5*min(self.size), 0.5*self.size[1] - 0.5*min(self.size)
            Color:
                rgba: .5, 0, 1, 1

            Ellipse:    
                size: 30, 30
                pos: 0.5*root.size[0]+25, 0.8*root.size[1]-25
            Color:
                rgba: 0.5, 0, 1"""
```

I also attached our Departments logo that I used for the example. I leave it to you to tweak sizes and add the appropriate resizing calls.[logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyYHI.png)